# How to construct constants in yii

Tags: php, constants

I am using Yii for my web application. In this I kept Constants class in model and extended

from `CUserIdentity` like..

```
class Constants extends CUserIdentity
{
 CONST ACCOUTN_ONE = 1;
 CONST ACCOUTN_TWO = 2;
 CONST ACCOUTN_THREE = 3;
}
```

Here I can access constants like `Constants::ACCOUTN_ONE` and it will return correct result as `1`

But when I start construct constants dynamically means..

```
$type = 'ONE';
$con = "Constants::ACCOUTN_".$type;
echo $con;
```

It will dispaly as Constants::ACCOUTN_ONE;

I am expecting here `1`

Please correct me if any mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$type = 'ONE'; // You created string

$con = "Constants::ACCOUTN_".$type; // Created other string

echo $con; // Printed it
```

You just printed string without evaluating it.
Yes, of couse it will dispaly as Constants::ACCOUTN_ONE;

You need to evaluate your  code with `eval()`(bad), or use this scheme:

`echo Constant($con);`

Comment: @abhi :thats not the way to do it, eval is really bad, use [$$](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: you're right, my bad, i still thing he should use static magic methods over the constant function

Answer (score 1):

```
$type = 'ONE';
$con = "Constants::ACCOUTN_".$type;
echo Constant($con);
```

Answer (score -1):

I do this with
 a class for it a while back:

```
/**
 * Lots of pixie dust and other magic stuff.
 *
 * Set a global: Globals::key($vlaue); @return void
 * Get a global: Globals::key(); @return mixed|null
 * Isset of a global: Globals::isset($key); @return bool
 *
 * Debug to print out all the global that are set so far: Globals::debug(); @return array
 *
*/
class Globals
{

    private static $_propertyArray = array();

    /**
     * Pixie dust
     *
     * @param $method
     * @param $args
     * @return mixed|bool|null
     * @throws MaxImmoException
     */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        if ($method == 'isset') {
            return isset(self::$_propertyArray[$args[0]]);
        } elseif ($method == 'debug') {
            return self::$_propertyArray;
        }

        if (empty($args)) {
            //getter
            if (isset(self::$_propertyArray[$method])) {
                return self::$_propertyArray[$method];
            } else {
                return null; //dont wonna trow errors when faking isset()
            }
        } elseif (count($args) == 1) {
            //setter
            self::$_propertyArray[$method] = $args[0];
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Too many arguments for property ({$method}).", 0);
        }

    }
}
```